# MongoDB update. Trying to set one field from a property of another

Tags: mongodb

What I'm trying  to do is pretty straightforward, but I can't find out how to give one field the value of another.

I simply want to update one field with the character count of another.

```
db.collection.update({$exists:true},{$set : {field1 : field2.length}})
```

I've tried giving it dot notation

```
db.collection.update({$exits:true},{$set : {field1: "this.field2.length"}})
```

As well as using javascript syntax

```
db.collection.update({$exits:true},
                     {$set : {field1: {$where : "this.field2.length"}})
```

But just copied the string and got a "notOkforstorage" respectively. Any help?

Update:
I only get the "notOkforStorage" when I query by ID:

```
db.collection.update({_id:ObjectID("38289842bbb")},
                     {$set : {field1: {$where :"this.field2.length"}}})
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
db.collection.find(your_querry).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.field1 = doc.field2.length;
  db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

You can use `your_querry` to select only part of the original collection do perform an update. If you want to process an entire collection, use `your_querry = {}`.

If you want all operations to be atomic, use `update` instead of `save`:

```
db.collection.find( your_querry, { field2: 1 } ).forEach(function(doc) {
  db.collection.update({ _id: doc._id },{ $set: { field1: doc.field2.length } } );
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update/creation of a field based on another field:

```
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5e84c..."), "field1" : 12, "field2" : "world" }
db.collection.update(
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5e84c...") },
  [{ $set: { field1: { $strLenCP: "$field2" } } }]
)
// { "_id" : ObjectId("5e84c..."), "field1" : 5, "field2" : "world" }
```

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update.
- The second part `[{ $set: { field1: { $strLenCP: "$field2" } } }]` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline). [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator and an alias for `$addFields`. Any aggregation operator can be used within the `$set` stage; in our case [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/index.html#exp._S_strLenCP) which provides the length of `field2`.

Comment: This should be the right answer. `forEach` on every `doc` is just too slow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your are using `exists` in the wrong way.
   `Syntax: { field: { $exists: <boolean> } }`
2. You use of [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_where) is also incorrect
   *Use the $where operator to pass either a string containing a JavaScript expression or a full JavaScript function to the query system*

   `db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.credits == this.debits" } );`
   `db.myCollection.find( { $where: "obj.credits == obj.debits" } );`

   `db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return (this.credits == this.debits) } } );`

   `db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return obj.credits == obj.debits; } } );`

I think you should use [Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Map reduce is not designed to update the originating collection, it is designed to create a new collection out of aggregated version of the previous collection.

Comment: I can use exists in this way.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know the easiest way is the read and write aproach:

```
//At first, get/prepare your new value:
var d= db.yourColl.fetchOne({....});
d.field1== d.field2.length;

// then update with your new value
db.yourColl.save(d);
```